# elpy installed in the virtual environment, but elpy-config says Not Found

Tags: python, elpy, install

I am running emacs-28.1 and starting of with `elpy`. My current python development section is as follows:

```
(use-package elpy
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :init
  (setq elpy-rpc-python-command "python3")
  (setq elpy-rpc-virtualenv-path 'current)
  (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook
        (lambda() (setq display-line-numbers 'relative)))
  (advice-add 'python-mode :before 'elpy-enable))
  ;;(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-enable-on-save))


(use-package pyvenv
  :ensure t
  :config
  (pyvenv-mode t)

  ;; Set correct python-interpretor
  (setq pyvenv-post-activate-hooks
    (list (lambda ()
        (setq python-shell-interpreter (concat pyvenv-virtual-env "bin/python3")))))
  (setq pyvenv-post-deactivate-hooks
    (list (lambda ()
        (setq python-shell-interpreter "python3"))))

  ;; Taken from "https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/managing-a-python-development-environment-in-emacs-43897fd48c6a"
  (setq pyvenv-use-alias 't)
  (setq pyvenv-set-path nil)

  ;;(global-pyenv-mode)
    (defun pyenv-update-on-buffer-switch (prev curr)
      (if (string-equal "Python" (format-mode-line mode-name nil nil curr))
          (pyenv-use-corresponding)))
    (add-hook 'switch-buffer-functions 'pyenv-update-on-buffer-switch))


(provide 'pydev)
```

My `elpy-config` output is as follows,

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 28.1
Elpy..............: Not found (Python), 1.35.0 (Emacs Lisp)
Virtualenv........: pyMachine (/home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine/)
Interactive Python: /home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine/bin/python3 3.10.5 (/home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine/bin/python3)
RPC virtualenv....: pyMachine (/home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine)
 Python...........: python3 nil (/home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine/bin/python3)
 Jedi.............: Not found
 Rope.............: Not found
 Autopep8.........: Not found
 Yapf.............: Not found
 Black............: Not found
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine/bin/flake8)

Warnings

The Python interpreter could not find the elpy module. Please report
to: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/new.

There was an unexpected problem starting the RPC process. Please check
the following output to see if this makes sense to you. To me, it
doesn't.

<string>:3: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
{"can_connect_to_pypi": true, "rpc_python_version": "3.10.5", "elpy_version": "1.35.0", "jedi_version": "0.18.1", "jedi_latest": null, "rope_version": "1.2.0", "rope_latest": null, "autopep8_version": "1.6.0", "autopep8_latest": null, "yapf_version": "0.32.0", "yapf_latest": null, "black_version": "22.6.0", "black_latest": null}
```

However, I have `elpy` installed in `emacs` and `Jedi` installed in virtual environment. I am just starting to use `emacs` for my python development. Could someone shed some light as to what am I doing wrong (or) missing?

I am having `company-mode` for my auto-complete for other languages, `haskell` and `rust`. I am finding hard to have it work for python (as I copied the code-snippets for `haskell` and `rust` from web. Any suggestion/help would be much appreciated.

`elpy-config` output after editing the `elpy.el` file under `~/.emacs.d/elpa/elpy-1.35` as follows:

```
(defvar elpy-config--get-config "import json
import sys
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=FutureWarning)

import requests

# Two sections commented below are default
# Chaged urllib2 to urllib3
# try:
#     import urllib3 as urllib
# except ImportError:
#     import urllib.request as urllib


# Check if we can connect to pypi quickly enough
# try:
#     response = urllib.urlopen('https://pypi.org/pypi', timeout=1)
#     CAN_CONNECT_TO_PYPI = True
# except:
#     CAN_CONNECT_TO_PYPI = False


# Adopted from 
# https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1588
def latest(package, version=None):
    try:
        response = requests.get('https://pypi.org/pypi/{package}/json'.format(package=package)).content
        latest = json.loads(response)['info']['version']
        if version is None or LooseVersion(version) < LooseVersion(latest):
            return latest
        else:
            return None
    except:
        return None

# This is the default code
# def latest(package, version=None):
#     if not CAN_CONNECT_TO_PYPI:
#         return None
#     try:
#         response = urllib.urlopen('https://pypi.org/pypi/{package}/json'.format(package=package),
#                timeout=2).read()
#         latest = json.loads(response)['info']['version']
#         if version is None or LooseVersion(version) < LooseVersion(latest):
#             return latest
#         else:
#             return None
#     except:
#         return None
. . .
```

My `elpy-config` output is below:

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 28.1
Elpy..............: Not found (Python), 1.35.0 (Emacs Lisp)
Virtualenv........: pyMachine (/home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine/)
Interactive Python: /home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine/bin/python3 3.10.5 (/home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine/bin/python3)
RPC virtualenv....: pyMachine (/home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine)
 Python...........: python3 nil (/home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine/bin/python3)
 Jedi.............: Not found
 Rope.............: Not found
 Autopep8.........: Not found
 Yapf.............: Not found
 Black............: Not found
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/bussler/VirtualEnvs/pyMachine/bin/flake8)

Warnings

The Python interpreter could not find the elpy module. Please report
to: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/new.

There was an unexpected problem starting the RPC process. Please check
the following output to see if this makes sense to you. To me, it
doesn't.

<string>:3: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
{"can_connect_to_pypi": true, "rpc_python_version": "3.10.5", "elpy_version": "1.35.0", "jedi_version": "0.18.1", "jedi_latest": null, "rope_version": "1.2.0", "rope_latest": null, "autopep8_version": "1.6.0", "autopep8_latest": null, "yapf_version": "0.32.0", "yapf_latest": null, "black_version": "22.6.0", "black_latest": null}

Elpy could not connect to Pypi (or at least not quickly enough) and
check if the python packages were up-to-date. You can still try to
update all of them:

[Update python packages]

The Jedi package is not currently installed. This package is needed
for code completion, code navigation and access to documentation.

[Install jedi]

No autoformatting package is currently installed. At least one is
needed (Autopep8, Yapf or Black) to perform autoformatting (`C-c C-r
f` in a python buffer).

[Install autopep8]
[Install yapf]
[Install black]
```

No change, however.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1588#issuecomment-590678810

Comment: Didn't help. I still have the same `elpy-config` output as before. I have edited my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `elpy`  should be installed in folder `elpa`, not in virtual
environment. It is of same rank and functionality as `company` package, for instance.
The package `python` should be loaded before `elpy`(aka you must load it in your emacs, with `(use-package 'python)`. Try to delete all caches and the virtualenv created if you moved `elpy` to folder `elpa`.

But there are some problems with this package as follows:

- As [described here](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy), this is not maintained
  at the moment; some small modifications are made however, from time to time.
- Read the file `setup.cfg` - this shows the package is valid for Python versions up to 3.4, or
  you are using the version 3.10. There is the risk to have false warning/errors for your
  code if you write something new/unknown for `elpy`, so a good idea is to avoid this
  package until it is up to date.

What can you do: see/install/use the [`eglot package`](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot),
works OK out the box with the setting shown on that page.

Another solution is the [Emacs LSP](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/).

Comment: Yes, it's just incompatibility conflict among Python 3.10 and ELPA version of Elpy. Serendipitously I've found solution: https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#manually-from-sources

Just check-out to the branch *add-new-py-version*